# Removing List Items on Completion When Leaving View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a small practice todo app I am building to learn SwiftUI, and I am able to create a list of tasks in CoreData and mark them as complete which sets isComplete to true and changes the image from an empty circle to a checkmark.

```
List {
    ForEach(taskItems, id: \.self) { item in
        HStack {
            if item.isComplete == true {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill").padding(5.0).foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/).font(.system(size: 24))
                .onTapGesture {
                    item.isComplete.toggle()
                    self.saveTasks()
                }
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "circle").padding(5.0).foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/).font(.system(size: 24))
                .onTapGesture {
                    item.isComplete.toggle()
                    self.saveTasks()
                }
            }
            Text("\(item.title)")
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 5.0)
    }
    .onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
}
```

However, I want these items to be removed from the list once the user has left the view (like the native iOS reminders app). I have a line of code in my fetch request that does remove the items from the list, but it removes them immediately.

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: TaskItem.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskItem.order, ascending: false)]
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isComplete == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
) var taskItems: FetchedResults<TaskItem>
```

On tap of the item images, how can I mark the item as complete but only remove the list item once the user leaves the view or the app? Many thanks!

[App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jrUL.png)

Comment: use onDisappear(perform:)?

Comment: In your onDelete function, just mark these Todos as isComplete, but don't delete them. On Disappear you can delete all the entities which have the state isComplete

Comment: I have worked on something similar and trying to use the toggle functionality in SwiftUI to show completed and Active. Any guidance in that direction @Dale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your highest parent view for example if your higher parent is Vstack then use

```
body {
VStack {
}
.onDisappear {
//perform removal of items
}
}
 

                   }
```